# EGit not adding files

Tags: eclipse, github, egit

I'm using EGit 2.1.0 and Eclipse Juno on Mac OS X 10.8.  (I have never used EGit before a couple of  hours ago.)

I have a private GitHub repository (it's for a school team project -- don't want my classmates cheating :P) and my files aren't all being added.

I selected all 12 of my projects in Eclipse and tried to commit them.  I went through the wizard and for some reason only 5 of them received the yellow cylinder icon (and one of the 5 doesn't have any of its files selected).  The rest have the question mark, which Google tells me means they're "untracked."  I've tried pushing, committing and adding to index on these projects/files in the project to no avail.  How do I get them on github?

Incidentally the 4 that completely work are the first 4 alphabetically and the one that received the icon but didn't commit any files is the 5th.  It makes me think that it was going through them, in order, and some sort of (unreported) error was encountered.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: So all these projects should be in the same repository, right? Does the _Error Log_ view have anything in it? Also, see in the _Git Repositories_ view if you have created multiple repositories by mistake.

Comment: Thanks for the reply!  Turns out my `.gitignore` file was the culprit...

Comment: I had a similar issue, I couldn't commit a new file with a question mark icon. I had to 'Add to Index' before commit and it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that `.gitignore` was ignoring the files that had `Sql` in it.  If your files are not being tracked, one point of investigation is to look at your `.gitignore` file in your root directory.